# Launch an Extension command at Visual Studio 2022 launch?

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-2022

I've written a VS 2022 Extension containing commands that I'd like to run at the launch of Visual Studio 2022.

The command run fine if executed from a menu item but I cannot determine where a call to the command should be placed if I wish it to be called immediately after VS 2022 starts.

The VS commandfile functions New() and InitializeAsync() do not appear to be called until the first command is launched by a menu item (because the extension isn't loaded until called upon).

Is there a method of making the extension ready/initialized so it can run a command at startup, or to run the command at startup and force it to initialize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure an AsyncPackage to auto-load with [the instructions here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/how-to-use-asyncpackage-to-load-vspackages-in-the-background?view=vs-2022). Note there is some asynchrony so if you need it to run *precisely* at certain point you may have issues; we limit the ability for that because when everybody writes their package to do something on startup, Visual Studio startup then takes forever.

Comment: Understandable about not wanting to slow the VS startup sequence. Ultimately, my goal is to perform my code in the solutionload event. I'll look into those instructions once I 'translate them into vb'.